# Markov Decision Processes and Control Engineering?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, markov-process, control-theory, linear-control

In a Markov Decision Process, one has a Markov chain with (left) regular stochastic matrix $P$ and a collection of "actions" $a_i$ one can have act on the system after it transitions via its "drift". In the absence of taking actions, the system should drift to its steady-state (open-loop) vector $\pi_{OL}$ with $P\pi_{OL} = \pi_{OL}$.

My question is, if we model the actions as occurring via some inputs $\{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ with matrix $B$, can we (always?) set up a feedback loop with gain matrix $K$ so that the matrix $P-BK$ of the closed-loop system 1) is a regular stochastic matrix and 2) has a prescribed steady-state closed-loop vector $\pi_{CL}$?

[image]

What, if anything, is known about this phenomenon?

(I bet if one has $n$ independent inputs $\{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}$ with full-rank matrix $B$, this problem always has a solution gain matrix $K$.)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question well enough but I think that any Markov decision process with a linearized random decision policy is itself just a Markov chain. More precisely, if your decisions are chosen from a fixed collection $D$, and you have transition $n \times n$ matrices $P(d)$ for every $d \in D$, and decisions are chosen through a linear policy governed by a $|D| \times n$ matrix $B$, then what you're studying is basically just an $n$-state Mrakov chain with transition probabilities $P_{ij} = \sum_{d} B_{di} P(d)_{ij}$.

Comment: I think the $u_i$'s are not deterministic, but can instead be chosen after each tranition by "the user", so $\{P, B, C, D\}$ is not an $n$-state Markov chain

Comment: (Having said that, if one does implement a deterministic policy [in your terminology/viewpoint] or feedback loop with deterministic gain matrix $K$ [in my terminology/viewpoint], it does indeed become itself just a Markov chain - the difference, tho, IMHO is that now it drifts towards a steady-state vector $\pi_{CL}$ of **our** choosing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $1_n=\begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and consider the system $\begin{cases} X^T1_n = 1_n \\ X\pi_{CL} = X\pi_{CL} \end{cases}$ ($X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$). Any solution $Q$ to this system of equations with $q_{ij} > 0$ will be a regular stochastic matrix that has $\pi_{CL}$ as its steady-state vector. This is not an eigenvalue/eigenvector linear algebra problem but instead should be able to be solved with linear algebra's reduced row echelon form and linear programming (to ensure the entries are positive).

If one then sets $K = B^{-1}(P-Q)$, then $K$ is the desired gain matrix for the closed-loop system.

Here is some MATLAB code implementing finding the gain matrix $K$ given $\{P, B, C, D\}$ and $\pi_{CL}$ http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/Math%20205/MATLAB/: MarkovJeff.m is a function finding a regular stochastic matrix $Q$ with $\pi_{CL}$ as its steady-state vector; placeJeff.m is a function that takes the inputs $P, B,$ and $\pi_{CL}$, calls MarkovJeff.m to find $Q$, then computes the gain matrix $K$; and closedLoop.m is a .m script wherein one specifies $\{P, B, C, D\}$ and $\pi_{CL}$, and the gain matrix $K$ is computed, calling placeJeff.m. It may require functions from [https://people.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/minimat/mfiles.zip](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Erobbin/minimat/mfiles.zip) to run.

http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/Math%20205/Octave/ has the same files, adapted for Octave. Again, it may require functions from [https://people.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/minimat/mfiles.zip](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Erobbin/minimat/mfiles.zip) to run.

This http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/Math%20205/MATLAB/MarkovChain.slx is a Simulink file implementing the discrete-time Marvov chain as an open-loop system; it drifts towards the open-loop steady-state vector $\pi_{OL}$.

[image: Open-Loop System]

Here
http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/Scripts/Math%20205/MATLAB/MarkovDecisionProcess.slx is a Simulink file implementing the discrete-time Markov decision process as a closed-loop feedback control system; it drifts towards the prescribed closed-loop steady-state vector $\pi_{CL}$.

[image: Closed-Loop Steady-State]

(Evidently, XCos is only able to handle scalar [SISO] signals, so I won't be posting a file.)

Comment: The catch is $B$ is generally low rank. I think the keyword you might be looking is eigenstructure assignment.